# How do terminal emulators receive input from keyboard

Tags: linux, ubuntu, x11, tty, pseudoterminal

Since terminal emulators are X11 applications, do they receive input from X11Server if we directly type into the corresponding terminal window?

In that case why would /dev/pts/N directory exists?

Do terminal emulator reject the  input events from X Server and directly read from /dev/pts/N?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Terminal emulators receive keyboard input as events from the X11 server (or other display server) to which they are connected.

`/dev/pts` exists so that the terminal emulator can simulate input for the programs running inside it. The emulator receives events from the display server, and translates them into events which it feeds into `/dev/pts/...`. Programs running inside the emulator take their input from `/dev/pts/...` instead of `/dev/tty...`.